# Kibana Customized Visualization with ES and Angular Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, elasticsearch, kibana

First, I try to make a custom visualization in Kibana with learning [here](https://www.timroes.de/2015/12/02/writing-kibana-4-plugins-simple-visualizations/).

Then, I want my custom visualization to display like the clock how many hits my elasticsearch index has dynamically .

So, I changed some codes in above tutorial but they don't work.

Chrome Devtools tells says `Error: The elasticsearch npm module is not designed for use in the browser. Please use elasticsearch-browser`

I know I had better use elasticsearch-browser perhaps.

However, I want to understand what is wrong or why.

`public/myclock.js`

```
define(function(require) {
    require('plugins/<my-plugin>/mycss.css');
    var module = require('ui/modules').get('<my-plugin>');
    module.controller('MyController', function($scope, $timeout) {
        var setTime = function() {
            $scope.time = Date.now();
            $timeout(setTime, 1000);
        };
        setTime();
        var es = function(){
            var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
            var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
              host: 'localhost:9200',
              log: 'trace'
            });
            client.search({
              index: 'myindex',

            }).then(function (resp) {
                $scope.tot = resp.hits.total;
            }, function (err) {
                console.trace(err.message);
            });
        };
        es();

    });

    function MyProvider(Private) {
        ...
    }

    require('ui/registry/vis_types').register(MyProvider);

    return MyProvider;
});
```

`public/clock.html`

```
<div class="clockVis" ng-controller="MyController">
     {{ time | date:vis.params.format }}
     {{tot}}
</div>
```

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the controller in angularjs treats the elasticsearch javascript client as if it was accessing from the browser.

To elude this, one choice will be by building **Server API** in index.js and then make kibana access to elasticsearch by executing http request.

## Example

### index.js

```
// Server API (init func) will call search api of javascript
export default function (kibana) {
  return new kibana.Plugin({
    require: ['elasticsearch'],

    uiExports: {
      visTypes: ['plugins/sample/plugin']
    },

    init( server, options ) {
      // API for executing search query to elasticsearch
      server.route({
        path: '/api/es/search/{index}/{body}',
        method: 'GET',
        handler(req, reply) {
          // Below is the handler which talks to elasticsearch
          server.plugins.elasticsearch.callWithRequest(req, 'search', {
            index: req.params.index,
            body:  req.params.body
          }).then(function (error, response) {
            reply(response);
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

### controller.js

In the controller, you will need to call GET request for above example.

```
$http.get( url ).then(function(response) {
  $scope.data = response.data;
}, function (response){
  $scope.err  = "request failed";
});
```

In my case, I used url instead of absolute or relative path since path of dashboard app was deep.

```
http://[serverip]:5601/iza/app/kibana#/dashboard/[Dashboard Name]

                                                   *

                                             Your here

http://[serverip]:5601/iza/[api path]

                           *
                       api path will start here
```

I used this [reference](https://www.timroes.de/2016/02/21/writing-kibana-plugins-custom-applications/) as an example.